# liburing / IORING_OP_PROVIDE_BUFFERS - wrong buffer assigned to read op

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel

I am playing with liburing and io_uring, the former is built from the master branch and for the latter i am using the kernel 5.8.0-rc3.

I am facing the issue I am going to explain on previous version of the kernel as well (5.7.6, 5.8.0-rc1).

The tests using the provide buffers look like working as expected.

I am trying to implement a network tcp/ip server using **IORING_FEAT_FAST_POLL** and **IORING_OP_PROVIDE_BUFFERS** and I am using https://github.com/frevib/io_uring-echo-server as code reference.

The issue I am facing is that the buffer id is always set to the last of the registered buffers but I can see that the actual buffer used by the kernel is not that.

I have reduced the amount of registered buffers to just 10 and added some debugging info, it's now printing the content of all the buffers

Upon the first RECV from the server I get in `cqe->flags >> 16` the ID of the buffer containing the data and it's the last one of the list, and I can see that it's containing the data but upon the second RECV the kernel now used the buffer id 0 (the first one) but `cqe->flags >> 16` is still containing the ID of the last one.

The cause of this is an invocation of `io_uring_prep_provide_buffers`, infact upon the second invocation the issues arise.

Out of curiosity I have also tried to register the buffers one by one using

```
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i<MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++) {
        sqe = io_uring_get_sqe(&ring);
        io_uring_prep_provide_buffers(sqe, bufs, MAX_MESSAGE_LEN, 1, group_id, i);
    }
```

instead of

```
    io_uring_prep_provide_buffers(sqe, bufs, MAX_MESSAGE_LEN, MAX_CONNECTIONS, group_id, 0);
```

The issue start immediately.

I have also entirely disabled the re-registration of the freed buffer and everything works as expected (I commented out the invocation of the function `add_provide_buf`).

From the documentation it looks like after the buffer is selected the expectation is to add it back if it's free to be used but clearly this is causing the issue.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: At first sight this looks like a bug. The echo server was working fin on Linux 5.6 + io_uring's IORING_OP_PROVIDE_BUFFERS branch. The most io_uring knowledge at the moment is at https://lore.kernel.org/io-uring/. You could try asking there.

Comment: @frevib I saw that you fixed your code and with the same kind of change mine works as well and, after having looked to the kernel source code I understand why as well. If you drop the answer I will mark it as correct! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the code with re-registering the buffer: https://github.com/frevib/io_uring-echo-server/commit/aa6f2a09ca14c6aa17779a22343b9e7d4b3c7994

Checkout the latest master branch, it should work now: https://github.com/frevib/io_uring-echo-server

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to be able to play with the buffers because I want to test a strategy I have in mind to avoid the doubling up of the sqes.
I want to use 1 groups of three times the size I need, 1 counter and a 1 bitmap to track the consumption.
The bitmap must always be a multiple of 256 bits, the exceeding part will always report no buffers to be returned.
This is to be able to go through the bitmap using AVX/AVX2 with the ability to search for UINT32_MAX (using _mm256_cmpeq_epi32 / _mm256_cmp_ps).

Comment: Every time a buffer can be returned the bitmap is updated and the counter incremented, if the counter hits a certain threshold the scan is triggered and the chunks of buffers that can be returned are added back to liburing.
If too many buffers will have been used, because of fragmentation, then the code will scan the buffer group and re-add the buffers in smaller chunks.
This I think will really help the performances.

Comment: These threads might be useful: 

https://twitter.com/hielkedv/status/1235223155666542594?s=21 

and 

https://lore.kernel.org/io-uring/08ef10c8-90f3-4777-89ab-f9245dc03466@www.fastmail.com/

Comment: Thanks for the links, I implemented the logic I mentioned but basically I ended up having to pre-allocate 4 times the necessary buffers (ie. to handle 200 connections I had to at least allocate 1000 buffers) and although it was really fast, almost without losing req/s compared to managing directly the buffers, I think it would totally defeat the point of using the automatic buffer selection that would help to reduce the pre-allocated memory. I think for now I will go with a slab allocator (as I was initially planning), I prefer to move these buffers around to have a zero-copy network stack.

Comment: Just a note, I had to over-allocate before the buffer fragmentation I started to face checking blocks of 32 and 8 buffers.